# requests.responce.json() function giving error "Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am getting jsondecode error when I am trying trying to print requests.responce.json() after running the post method.

```
import requests
import requests_ntlm,json
import sharepy
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
base_url = 'https://company.sharepoint.com'
folderUrl = 'Shared Documents'
headers = {
"Accept":"application/jason; odata=verbose",
"Content-Type":"application/jason; odata=verbose",
"odata": "verbose",
"X-RequestDigest":"true"
}
r1 = sharepy.connect(base_url,username='user@company.onmicrosoft.com',password='password')
filename = 'testupload.mp4'
request_url = base_url + '/_api/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(\'''Shared Documents''\')/Files/add(url=\'' + filename + '\',overwrite=true)'
k = r1.post(url= base_url +"/_api/contextinfo",headers=headers)
print(k.json())
```

i am getting below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sharepointextended.py", line 28, in <module>
print(json.loads(k.content.decode('utf-8')))
File 
"C:\Users\saipr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", 
line 348, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File 
"C:\Users\saipr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", 
line 337, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File 
"C:\Users\saipr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", 
line 355, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like typo in your request headers. 
I am assuming the value should be 'application/json' and not 'application/jason'.

Please ignore this answer if this doesnt help as I am new to python. But, I dont think the post call would have been successful in line with general XMLHTTPRequest implementations.